# Elixir - Phoenix / Ecto - using multiple foreign keys to setup a has_many relationship

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have 4 modules, a `Studio`, a `Studio Type`, a `Site`, and a `Config`. The setup is that each site has many studios and configs, and so does each studio type. This means both studios and configs have a site ID and studio type ID:

Studio:

- id
- site_id
- studio_type_id

Config:

- id
- site_id
- studio_type_id

Site:

- id

StudioType:

- id

I’m trying to setup a has_many relationship between studios and configs, but I’m not sure how. I’ve tried:

```
defmodule Studio do
    has_many :configs, Config, foreign_key: [:site_id, :studio_type_id]
end
```

But this `foreign_key` option only accepts single entries. Is this setup even possible with ecto, or would I need a custom function in the Studio module to load associated configs? i’m keen to avoid changing the primary key of the studios table.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: This is in a no way a valid relationship, relationships are based around singular foreign keys. You need to have either a direct foreign key between config and studio, or a classical mapping table if your relation is many to many.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have defined

Studio

```
schema "studios" do
belongs_to :site, WhatEverYourSiteModuleIsNamed
belongs_to :studio_type, WhatEverYourStudioTypeModuleIsNamed
```

Config

```
schema "configs" do
belongs_to :site, WhatEverYourSiteModuleIsNamed
belongs_to :studio_type, WhatEverYourStudioTypeModuleIsNamed
```

Site

```
schema "sites" do
has_many :studios, WhatEverYourStudioModuleIsNamed
has_many :configs, WhatEverYourConfigsModuleIsNamed
```

Hope this example clears up some things